# Maven + AndroidAnnotations generated but not reachable classes

Tags: android, maven, android-annotations

Alright.

I'm attempting to create a project which is perfectly build able by using maven, and maven only.

Currently I'm facing this issue of classes being generated, and working fine, as long as there is no reference in actual java code.

Meaning, that if I create an example as in the [documentation](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/blob/develop/examples/maveneclipse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/androidannotations/maveneclipse/HelloAndroidActivity.java) it works.

As soon as I do something like

> Intent i = new Intent(SettingsActivity_);

then the build fails with

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project InterestingFind: 
>   Compilation failure cannot find symbol

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable DerpActivity_
location: class be.company.android.DisplayMapActivity
```

The files however, do get generated, as you can see in the image attached, but when the project is looked at in en Eclipse view, they are solely seen as normal folders, and not as 'source folder'.

This might explain why they are not picked up, but gives me a bit of a headache.
I cloned an android archetype, the release build.

Please, be of assistance if you in some way think you can aid me with this problem![image: Project structure]

> http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
>       4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>be.idamediafoundry</groupId>
    <artifactId>InterestingFind-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>be.idamediafoundry</groupId>
<artifactId>InterestingFind</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>InterestingFind - Application</name>
<properties>
    <androidannotations.version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</androidannotations.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots-repository</id>
        <name>Sonatype oss snapshot repo</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.akquinet.android.androlog</groupId>
        <artifactId>androlog</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId> org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- AndroidAnnotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.androidannotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
        <version>${androidannotations.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.androidannotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>androidannotations-api</artifactId>
        <version>${androidannotations.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Needed for androidannotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-android-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google Play Services : Should be compiled and added to local repo -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
        <version>5</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>


        <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
            <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
            <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
            <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
            <sdk>
                <platform>15</platform>
            </sdk>
            <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process-classes-with-proguard</id>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>proguard</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <proguardVersion>4.4</proguardVersion>
                                <maxMemory>256m</maxMemory>
                                <injar>classes</injar>
                                <libs>
                                    <lib>${rt.jar.path}</lib>
                                    <lib>${jsse.jar.path}</lib>
                                </libs>
                                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                                <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                                <proguardInclude>${project.basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                            <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
                            <version>4.4</version>
                            <scope>runtime</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign-application-apk</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>zipalign-application-apk</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>zipalign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>true</release>
                        <zipalign>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <inputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.apk</inputApk>
                            <outputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-signed-aligned.apk</outputApk>
                        </zipalign>
                        <sign>
                            <debug>false</debug>
                        </sign>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>${project.build.directory}/proguard_map.txt</file>
                                <type>map</type>
                                <classifier>release</classifier>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-signed-aligned</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Parent Pom :

> http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
>       4.0.0

```
<groupId>be.idamediafoundry</groupId>
<artifactId>InterestingFind-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>InterestingFind - Parent</name>

<modules>
    <module>InterestingFind</module>
    <module>InterestingFind-it</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <platform.version>4.1.1.4</platform.version>
    <android-plugin>3.5.1</android-plugin>
    <spring-android-version>1.0.1.RELEASE</spring-android-version>
    <sign.keystore>${project.basedir}/my-release-key.keystore</sign.keystore>
    <sign.alias>
    </sign.alias>
    <sign.storepass>
    </sign.storepass>
    <sing.keypass>
    </sing.keypass>

</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>codehaus-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Androlog is a logging and reporting library for Android -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.akquinet.android.androlog</groupId>
            <artifactId>androlog</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>15</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <removeExistingSignatures>true</removeExistingSignatures>
                    <archiveDirectory />
                    <archive>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</archive>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <certs>true</certs>
                    <keystore>${sign.keystore}</keystore>
                    <alias>${sign.alias}</alias>
                    <storepass>${sign.storepass}</storepass>
                    <keypass>${sign.keypass}</keypass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
                        <version>4.4</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <proguardVersion>4.4</proguardVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>performRelease</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${android-plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>true</release>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>enforce-signing-properties</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enforce</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <requireProperty>
                                        <property>sign.keystore</property>
                                        <message>The 'sign.keystore' property is missing. It must
                                            contain the path to the
                                            keystore used to sign the
                                            application.
                                        </message>
                                    </requireProperty>
                                    <requireFilesExist>
                                        <files>
                                            <file>${sign.keystore}</file>
                                        </files>
                                        <message>The 'sign.keystore' property does not point to a
                                            file. It must contain the
                                            path to the keystore used to sign
                                            the application.
                                        </message>
                                    </requireFilesExist>
                                    <requireProperty>
                                        <property>sign.alias</property>
                                        <message>The 'sign.alias' property is missing. It must
                                            contain the key alias used to
                                            sign the application.
                                        </message>
                                    </requireProperty>
                                    <requireProperty>
                                        <property>sign.storepass</property>
                                        <message>The 'sign.storepass' property is missing. It must
                                            contain the password of
                                            the keystore used to sign the
                                            application.
                                        </message>
                                    </requireProperty>
                                    <requireProperty>
                                        <property>sign.keypass</property>
                                        <message>The 'sign.keypass' property is missing. It must
                                            contain the password of the
                                            key used to sign the application.
                                        </message>
                                    </requireProperty>
                                </rules>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>linux</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>unix</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <rt.jar.path>${java.home}/jre/lib/rt.jar</rt.jar.path>
            <jsse.jar.path>${java.home}/jre/lib/jsse.jar</jsse.jar.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- mac profile has to be after unix since running on mac will trigger 
        both -->
    <profile>
        <id>mac</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>mac</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- absolute path -->
            <!--<rt.jar.path>/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/classes.jar</rt.jar.path> -->
            <!-- or with JAVA_HOME /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/ -->
            <rt.jar.path>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</rt.jar.path>
            <jsse.jar.path>${java.home}/../Classes/jsse.jar</jsse.jar.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>windows</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <rt.jar.path>${java.home}/jre/lib/rt.jar</rt.jar.path>
            <jsse.jar.path>${java.home}/jre/lib/jsse.jar</jsse.jar.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

***Edit : updated pom.***
***Edit : uploaded [Log file](http://pastebin.com/SBwEx5kq)***

Comment: did you try to put `<extensions>true</extensions>` in the parent pom.xml ?

Comment: @ben75 Yes, it is in the parent pom.

Comment: I mean for the maven-android-plugin (in your post : the `<extensions>true</extensions>` is only in the application pom. Can you update your post with your actual pom.xml ?)

Comment: @ben75 Done, do you mean the android generation plugin?

Comment: @ben75 Thanks for suggesting that, but it was to no avail. Please feel free to give suggestions ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem was caused by a dependency not being resolved.

At first Maven did not even report this missing dependency, until I started removing things from my pom which I had added in an attempt to resolve this issue.

Now, what explains that the dependency didn't get auto-resolved, is the fact that there is no such artifact on the central maven repository.

As such, I added the following repository :

```
<repositories>
    <!-- For developing with Android ROME Feed Reader -->
    <repository>
        <id>android-rome-feed-reader-repository</id>
        <name>Android ROME Feed Reader Repository</name>
        <url>https://android-rome-feed-reader.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Resulting in that 'hidden' dependency being resolved.

This dependency seems to be needed by the

```
    <!-- Needed for androidannotations REST interface-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-android-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

[Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e68) report that this 'hidden dependency' of which we're speaking is needed for RSS and Atom feed support by the rest-template.

What made this even weirder is that the initial activity annotated by AA got created and resolved nicely. As long as I didn't refer to a generated class, e.g. for navigation, then it did compile and run.
From the moment I tried to use a class_ in code however, it went down this path.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Well... In your maven-processor-plugin configuration you're using the old package naming for the AA processor (ie : `com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor`).

As you're using the 3.0-SNAPSHOT, you should modify it to use the new one : `org.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor`

Also, I'm not sure you really need this plugin to make AA works.

Comment: Thanks, normally it shouldn't be needed, but I added that just for being sure. I'll remove it and update pom accordingly.

Comment: No, I uploaded the log file, complete debug. Only a warning about platform-encoding. Thanks for taking the time