# AndroidAnnotations - cannot find symbol when using maven (missing imports)

Tags: java, android, maven, android-annotations

AndroidAnnotations 3.0.1.

```
package com.myapp;
import com.myapp.view.MyView_;
// other imports...

@EActivity(R.layout.start)
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @ViewById
    MyView_ myView;

    // using myView
}
```

And my custom view:

```
package com.myapp.view;
// imports...
@EView
public class MyView extends TextView {
    // ...
}
```

I have imported my project to Android Studio as Maven project. When I build it from Studio, everything works.

However, when I try to `mvn package` it, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /e:/projects/myapp/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/myapp/MyActivity_.java:[80,22] cannot find symbol
 symbol:   class MyView_
 location: class com.myapp.MyActivity_
```

When I open the `MyActivity_.java` generated file, I can see that there are no import for `com.myapp.view.MyView_` class (it is there when I build with Studio). Why could that happen?

Compiler configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <annotationProcessors>
            <annotationProcessor>org.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
        </annotationProcessors>
        <compilerArguments>
            <AandroidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml</AandroidManifestFile>
        </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15565600/878514) does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use generated class on your `@ViewById` annotated field. But you still have to use generated one in your layout file :

```
@EActivity(R.layout.start)
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @ViewById
    MyView myView;
}

<LinearLayout ...>
     <my.package.MyView_ .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, could you confirm you have these dependencies in your pom.xml and you're using Java 6 (as explained [on the wiki](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Maven#pom-configuration)) ?

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- [...] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.androidannotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.androidannotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>androidannotations-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Many thanks. Indeed, changing the type of field from `MyView_` to `MyView` solved the problem. I accidentally put a generated class reference there. And no - I will try to use Java 7 as long as I could due to diamonds and multicatch ;)

Comment: This sure is good features. But as I'm not sure it's totally compatible with Android, I'm not using it. Do you have any feedback to give about this ?